# CSS : When display size is reduced,a <div> is still floating even i set the clearfix

Tags: html, css

I'm making a homepage look like this one: https://www.daum.net/

When the display is reduced(between the size of 800 px and 1280px - i made a media query when under 800px), this site has overflow-x scroll but mine doesn't look like that

By the way, the login form seems floating when I reduced the size as well even I set the clearfix.

And I assume that it would make x-scroll doesn't work correctly.

Please check this code

+)ADD EXPLAN

I'm still struggling with this homepage. I made a media query when the size is only under 800. When the size is above 800px, the x-scroll should work. It seems to work thankfully but The login form is floating when user reducing the size of display like this. This is what i've want.

(Screenshot at the moment )

[image]

It must look like this (Expected Result)

[image]

```css
/* NOTE:
 * Grid layout stuff starts at line 138. 
 */

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
CSS Reset
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
html {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 -ms-text-size-adjust:     100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.wrapper {
 margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}


.homepage-content-wrapper{
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

ul{list-style: none;}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
Accessibility
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Text meant only for screen readers */
.screen-reader-text {
 clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
 position: absolute !important;
 height: 1px;
 width: 1px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.screen-reader-text:hover,
.screen-reader-text:active,
.screen-reader-text:focus {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 clip: auto !important;
 color: #21759b;
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: auto;
 left: 5px;
 line-height: normal;
 padding: 15px 23px 14px;
 text-decoration: none;
 top: 5px;
 width: auto;
 z-index: 100000; /* Above WP toolbar */
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
Typography
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
 color: #404040;
 font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 1em 0;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
General styles
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.site {
 background: #ededed;
 min-height: 100vh;
}

.main-content,
.main-homepage-content,
.twin,
.footer {
 padding: 1em 2em;
}

.masthead{
    padding: 1em 0em;
    color: white;
}

.sidebar{padding:1em 0.375em; }

.main-content,
.main-homepage-content{
 background: white;
}

.news-container{width:100%;}

.colophon {
 padding: 2em;
 background: #3E454C;
 color: white;
}

.colophon a {
 color: white;
}

.colophon a:hover,
.colophon a:focus {
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.column-left{position: relative; float: left; width: 900px;}
.column-right{position: relative; float: right; width: 300px;}

.main-homepage-content:after,
.column-left:after,
#main-ad:after,
.column-right:after{content: ""; clear: both; display: table;}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .column-left{width: 100%;}
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
If no grid support, limit width to 50em and center align
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
@supports not (display: grid) {
 .wrapper {
  max-width: 50em;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
CSS Grid layout for wider screens, when browser supports grid:
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
 @supports (display: grid) {

  .content-wrapper {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(6, minmax(auto, 10em)) 1fr;
   grid-template-rows: minmax(1em, auto) 1fr auto minmax(1em, auto);
  }
        
        .homepage-content-wrapper {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 100%;
   grid-template-rows: minmax(1em, auto) 1fr auto minmax(1em, auto);
  }
        
        .column-left{
            grid-column-start: 1;
            grid-column-end: 2;
            grid-row-start: 1;
            grid-row-end: 2;
        }
        
        .column-right{
            grid-column-start: 2;
            grid-column-end: 3;
            grid-row-start: 1;
            grid-row-end: 2;
        }

  .masthead,
  .colophon {
   grid-column: span 12;
  }

  .main-content {
   grid-column: 2/12;
  }

  .sidebar {
   grid-column: 1/1;
  }
        

 }
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
Login &Search Form & Logo
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.header-level-1{
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.header-level-1 .clearlist{
    float:right;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.header-level-1 .clearlist:after{content: ""; clear: both; display: table;}

.header-level-1 .clearlist li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    float:left;
}

.header-level-1 .clearlist li a{
    display: block;
    font: normal 11px 돋움;
    color: #585858;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-align: center;
}
.header-level-1 .clearlist li:not(:first-child)  a::before {
content: "|";}

/*
.header-level-1 .clearlist li a:before {
    content: "|";
}
.header-level-1 .clearlist li:first-child a:before {
  content: "";
}*/

.header-level-2 {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-level-2-1{width:100px; float:left}
.header-level-2-2{width:auto;}

.header-level-2-1:after,
.header-level-2-2:after{
    content: ""; clear: both; display: table;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px)
.logo-image{
    grid-column: 1/1;
}

.search-form {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo-image:after,.search-form:after{content: ""; clear: both; display: table;}

.search-form form {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.search-form .inner-form {
  background: #fff;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field {
  height: 68px;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field input {
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field input.placeholder {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field input:hover, .search-form form .inner-form .input-field input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap {
  width: 150px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .choices__inner {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  box-sizing: unset !important;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .choices__inner .choices__list.choices__list--single {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .choices__inner .choices__item.choices__item--selectable.choices__placeholder {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #888;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .choices__inner .choices__list--single .choices__item {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  color: #555;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .choices[data-type*="select-one"]:after {
  right: 30px;
  border-color: #e5e5e5 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .choices__list.choices__list--dropdown {
  border: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .choices__list.choices__list--dropdown .choices__item--selectable {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .choices__list--dropdown .choices__item--selectable.is-highlighted {
  background: #fff;
  color: #eb008b;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .choices__list--dropdown .choices__item {
  color: #555;
  min-height: 24px;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap {
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
      flex-grow: 1;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.third-wrap {
  width: 74px;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.third-wrap .btn-search {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eb008b;
  transition: all .2s ease-out, color .2s ease-out;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.third-wrap .btn-search svg {
  width: 16px;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.third-wrap .btn-search:hover {
  background: #eb008b;
}

.search-form form .inner-form .input-field.third-wrap .btn-search:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .search-form form .inner-form .input-field {
    height: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .header-level-2-2{width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;}
    
  .header-level-1 .clearlist{
     position: absolute;
     top: 5em;
     right: 0.275em;
    }
    
  .logo-image{
    display: none;
    }
  .search-form {
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;   
    }
  .search-form form .inner-form {
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-top:5em;
  }
  .search-form form .inner-form .input-field {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  .search-form form .inner-form .input-field input {
    padding: 10px 15px;
  }
  .search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 0;
  }
  .search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .choices__inner {
    padding: 10px 15px;
  }
  .search-form form .inner-form .input-field.first-wrap .choices[data-type*="select-one"]:after {
    right: 11.5px;
    border-color: #e5e5e5 transparent transparent transparent;
  }
  .search-form form .inner-form .input-field.second-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .search-form form .inner-form .input-field.third-wrap {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
    
  .choices__list--dropdown {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2.5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2.5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
}
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
Navigation:
--------------------------------------------------------------*/


.nav-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.nav-header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.nav-header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#666 !important;
}

.nav-header li a:hover,
.nav-header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #eb008b;
  color: #fff!important;
}

/* menu */

.nav-header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.nav-header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.nav-header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.nav-header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.nav-header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.nav-header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.nav-header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.nav-header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 400px;
}

.nav-header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.nav-header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}


@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .nav-header {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:1em;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  .nav-header:after{content: ""; clear: both; display: table;}
    
  .nav-header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .nav-header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .nav-header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
HomePage
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#loginForm{background-color: #e9ecef;}

.login-input{
    margin: 50px 0 0 30px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 156px;
}

.login-input input{
    width: 100%;
}

.login-input input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 3;
    padding-left:5px;
}

.btn-login{    
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: white;
}

.login-set {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.list-user {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 270px;
    padding: 15px 0 30px 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.list-user li {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 1px 10px;
}

.tab-content {
    height: 360px;
}

.tab-pane ul{
    width:400px;
}

.list_thumb li {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 160px;
}

.list_thumb li:last-child:after{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #main-ad,
    .column-right{display: none;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-slider"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> 
    </head>
    
<body> 
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="masthead">
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="header-level-1">
            <!-- Login -->
                <ul class="clearlist">
                    <li><a href="#">로그인</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">회원가입</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">소개</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="header-level-2">
            <!-- Logo and Title -->
            <div class="header-level-2-1">   
            <div class="logo-image" >
               <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#"></a>
            </div>
            </div> 
            
        </div>                                                                                                                
        <nav>
        <!-- Navigation-->    
            <div class="nav-header">
            <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
            <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">신문줄광고</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">신문보기</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">부동산</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">알뜰장터</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">자동차</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">커뮤니티</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>    
        </nav>
    </header><!-- .masthead -->
        
    <div class="homepage-content-wrapper">
    <!-- Main Content -->  
    <main class="main-homepage-content">
    <div class="column-left">
    <!-- AD TOP -->
        <div id="main-ad">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x170.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <!-- NEWS Section -->
        <div class="news-container">
                <ul class="nav" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="allnews-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#allnews" role="tab" aria-controls="allnews" aria-selected="true">전체기사</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="politic-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#politic" role="tab" aria-controls="politic" aria-selected="false">정치/이민</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="economy-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#economy" role="tab" aria-controls="economy" aria-selected="false">경제</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="society-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#society" role="tab" aria-controls="society" aria-selected="false">사회</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="entertain-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#entertain" role="tab" aria-controls="entertain" aria-selected="false">연예/스포츠</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="allnews" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="allnews-tab">
                        <ul class="list_thumb">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="link_item">
                                <span class="thumb_g">
                                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/154x94.jpg" width="154" height="94" class="img_thumb" alt="">
                                </span>
                                <div class="cont_item">
                                <strong class="tit_item">산다라박, 오늘 화제가 됐던 그 옷 맞습니다</strong>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="link_item">
                                <span class="thumb_g">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/154x94.jpgg" width="154" height="94" class="img_thumb" alt=""></span>
                                <div class="cont_item">
                                    <strong class="tit_item">한소희, '백일의 낭군님' 종방연 참석한 세자빈</strong>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="link_item"><span class="thumb_g">
                                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/154x94.jpg" width="154" height="94" class="img_thumb" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="cont_item">
                                        <strong class="tit_item">소희 '격한 안무에도 미모유지~'</strong>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="link_item">
                                    <span class="thumb_g">
                                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/154x94.jpg" width="154" height="94" class="img_thumb" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="cont_item">
                                        <strong class="tit_item">'여우각시별' 김지수, 이제훈을 감싸는 이유 고...</strong>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="politic" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="politic-tab">
                          정치/이민
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="economy" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="economy-tab">
                          경제
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="society" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="society-tab">
                          사회
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="entertain" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="entertain-tab">
                          연예
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!-- NEWS Section -->
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">
    <!-- 로그인 -->
    <form id="loginForm" name="loginform" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="login-input">
                <label class="" for="kyocha_id" style="display: none;">아이디</label>
                    <input type="text" id="kyocha_id" name="kyocha_id" class="tf_login" maxlength="50" placeholder="아이디" tabindex="1">
                <label class="" for="kyocha_pwd" style="display: none;">비밀번호</label>
                    <input type="password" id="kyocha_pwd" name="kyocha_pwd" class="tf_login tf_pw" maxlength="32" placeholder="비밀번호" tabindex="2">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="loginSubmit" class="btn-login #loginbtn" tabindex="3" onclick="">
                <span class="ir_wa">로그인</span>
            </button>
            <div class="login-set">
                <span class="info_check">
     <input type="checkbox" id="stln" name="stln" class="inp_steady" tabindex="4" onclick="">
                    <label id="lbStln" class="lab_steady" for="stln" onclick="">
                        <span class="ico_login ico_check"></span>로그인 상태 유지
                    </label>
                </span>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-user">
                <li class="fst">
                    <a href="" class="link_join #registration" tabindex="5" onclick="">회원가입</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" class="link_find #id" tabindex="6" onclick="">아이디<span class="screen_out">찾기</span></a>
                    <span class="ico_dot">·</span>
                    <a href="" class="link_find find_pw #password" tabindex="7" onclick=""> 비밀번호 찾기</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </form>
    <!-- //로그인 -->
    </div>
    
    </main>
    </div> 
    
    <footer class="colophon grid">
        <aside></aside>
    </footer>
</div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    
</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't contain any reference to overflow-x or y. It does have a horizontal scrollbar at certain widths though.

Comment: @MrLister I'm sorry ! updated

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what the problem is? You say it doesn't work as expected, but we can't see what you're expecting. E.g. the scrollbar is now visible at all widths; is that what you want?

Comment: @MrLister i edit the question and add expected image ! Please have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting your question, but in looking at your expected result image it appears you want a portion of your webpage to overflow horizontally while in a desktop viewport.

By simply changing the following rule from:

```
.homepage-content-wrapper{
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

To:

```
.homepage-content-wrapper{
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You should see your login form remain to the right of your place holder image even when your viewport is under 1280px wide.